# Creating a custom array with jBuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jbuilder

I'm trying to use jBuilder to construct a custom array which is the needed structure for my javascript function. In this case their is only 1 object in the array. I am aware of the `array!` method, but that requires the use of a collection. How do I force jbuilder to wrap an array around the object? Structure I'm looking for is shown below:

```
object = {
  customArray : [{ someKey : 'somevalue' }]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you are asking, but you can do:

```
x = { :someKey => 'somevalue' }
Jbuilder.encode do |json|
  json.customArray Array.wrap(x)
end
```

`Array#wrap` is provided by `ActiveSupport` and will wrap an item in an array (unless it is an array). It also won't break your `Hash` like other methods do (e.g., `Array(x)`, `x.to_a`, `[*x]`).